# How to send to odoo an image of mysql to postgresql via xml rpc

Tags: image, web-services, xml-rpc, odoo

I try to develop a connector to my ecommerce platform to Odoo.
Currently I have a problem concerning the images.
My image is on my ecommerce platform inside mysql like this /catalog/image/toto.jpg

I want insert this image inside odoo platform (products), how to do this, just insert in xml rpc code this : http://www.mydomain/catalog/image/toto.jpg ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just a comment from [Odoo source code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/osv/fields.py#L528):

```
    # Binary values may be byte strings (python 2.6 byte array), but
    # the legacy OpenERP convention is to transfer and store binaries
    # as base64-encoded strings. The base64 string may be provided as a
    # unicode in some circumstances, hence the str() cast in symbol_f.
    # This str coercion will only work for pure ASCII unicode strings,
    # on purpose - non base64 data must be passed as a 8bit byte strings.
```

So you need to read image file and posibly encode it in base64. and result pass to Binary field.

If your image is on file system it would be something like:

```
import base64
img = open('path to my img', 'rb').read()
data = base64.b64encode(img)
# Write data to odoo
```

Also You may use [openerp_proxy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openerp_proxy/) project to simplify xml-rpc related work

Comment: Hi Thank you,
But my webservice is is php and use xml rpc. How to do send my image.